# ClassCastException when casting JAXBElement to DynamicEntity

Tags: java, eclipselink, moxy

I followed [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic/JAXBContextFromXMLSchema) and [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Dynamic/XmlToDynamicEntity) examples, and it worked fine.
Then I changed the xml and xsd file for another that imports 3 other xsd and I keep getting this:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicEntity
```

I implemented the EntityResolver and checked the locations of all xml files, set the noCorrectnessCheck property to true, but can't make this work.

Here is the first XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/pmac/servico-saldo-req"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:pmac-saldo="http://mycompany.com/pmac/servico-saldo-req"
xmlns:pmac-entrada="http://mycompany.com/pmac/modo-entrada-siper"
xmlns:pmac-header="http://mycompany.com/pmac/header" xmlns:pmac-neg="http://mycompany.com/pmac/pmac-negocial">

<import schemaLocation="modo-entrada-siper.xsd"
    namespace="http:/mycompany.com/pmac/modo-entrada-siper">
</import>
<import schemaLocation="header-pmac.xsd"
    namespace="http://mycompany.com/pmac/header">
</import>
<import schemaLocation="pmac-negocial.xsd" namespace="http://mycompany.com/pmac/pmac-negocial"></import>
<complexType name="servico">
    <sequence>
        <element name="header" type="pmac-header:header-pmac"
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="modo-entrada"
            type="pmac-entrada:entrada-siper" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="negocial" type="pmac-neg:consulta-saldo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="servico-canal" type="pmac-saldo:servico"></element>
</schema>
```

Here is the first import:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/pmac/modo-entrada-siper" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pmac-entrada="http://mycompany.com/pmac/modo-entrada-siper">

<complexType name="entrada-siper">
    <sequence>
        <element name="codigo-modo" type="int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="opcao" type="int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="cpf" type="string" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="token" type="pmac-entrada:token-siper" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="token-siper">
    <sequence>
        <element name="acao" type="int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="sessao" type="string" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="endereco-ip" type="string" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="token-sessao" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
</schema>
```

The second import:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/pmac/header" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pmac-header="http://mycompany.com/pmac/header">

<complexType name="header-pmac">
    <sequence>
        <element name="versao" type="int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="codigo-canal" type="int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="codigo-servico" type="int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="nsu-canal" type="int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="data-solicitacao" type="date" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="hora-solicitacao" type="time" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="data-contabil" type="date" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="hora-contabil" type="time" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
</schema>
```

And the third import:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/pmac/pmac-negocial" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:pmac-neg="http://mycompany.com/pmac/pmac-negocial">

<complexType name="conta">
    <sequence>
        <element name="agencia-conta" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="int">
                    <pattern value="[0-9]{4}"></pattern>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </element>
        <element name="operacao-conta" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="int">
                    <pattern value="[0-9]{3}"></pattern>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </element>
        <element name="numero-conta" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="int">
                    <pattern value="[0-9]{8}"></pattern>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </element>
        <element name="dv-conta" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <simpleType>
                <restriction base="int">
                    <pattern value="[0-9]{1}"></pattern>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="consulta-saldo">
    <sequence>
        <element name="conta-sidec" type="pmac-neg:conta"
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        </element>
        <element name="tipo-saldo" type="string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
</schema>
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmac-saldo:servico-canal xmlns:pmac-entrada="http://mycompany.com/pmac/modo-entrada-siper"
xmlns:pmac-header="http://mycompany.com/pmac/header" xmlns:pmac-neg="http://mycompany.com/pmac/pmac-negocial"
xmlns:pmac-saldo="http://mycompany.com/pmac/servico-saldo-req"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://mycompany.com/pmac/servico-saldo-req ../schema/servico-saldo-req.xsd ">
<pmac-saldo:header>
    <pmac-header:versao>1</pmac-header:versao>
    <pmac-header:codigo-canal>3</pmac-header:codigo-canal>
    <pmac-header:codigo-servico>000001</pmac-header:codigo-servico>
    <pmac-header:nsu-canal>1</pmac-header:nsu-canal>
    <pmac-header:data-solicitacao>2013-07-05</pmac-header:data-solicitacao>
    <pmac-header:hora-solicitacao>18:00:00</pmac-header:hora-solicitacao>
    <pmac-header:data-contabil>2013-07-18</pmac-header:data-contabil>
    <pmac-header:hora-contabil>10:00:00</pmac-header:hora-contabil>
</pmac-saldo:header>
<pmac-saldo:modo-entrada>
    <pmac-entrada:codigo-modo>1</pmac-entrada:codigo-modo>
    <pmac-entrada:opcao>0</pmac-entrada:opcao>
    <pmac-entrada:cpf>03432252200</pmac-entrada:cpf>
    <pmac-entrada:token>
        <pmac-entrada:acao>1</pmac-entrada:acao>
        <pmac-entrada:sessao>3c95ce29b0d4d6c00b467a3871aac</pmac-entrada:sessao>
        <pmac-entrada:endereco-ip>127.0.0.1</pmac-entrada:endereco-ip>
        <pmac-entrada:token-sessao>WHUxpCMkyuF7xCXUJJt6tgFupGHXzg6HfX92rz4UBIK6AbvIcXH93sg7rNid</pmac-entrada:token-sessao>
    </pmac-entrada:token>
</pmac-saldo:modo-entrada>
<pmac-saldo:negocial>
    <pmac-neg:conta-sidec>
        <pmac-neg:agencia-conta>1679</pmac-neg:agencia-conta>
        <pmac-neg:operacao-conta>001</pmac-neg:operacao-conta>
        <pmac-neg:numero-conta>00000155</pmac-neg:numero-conta>
        <pmac-neg:dv-conta>8</pmac-neg:dv-conta>
    </pmac-neg:conta-sidec>
    <pmac-neg:tipo-saldo>disponivel</pmac-neg:tipo-saldo>
</pmac-saldo:negocial>
</pmac-saldo:servico-canal>
```

Comment: Share the XML and code to provide some context to your problem